# ifeq issue: compare 2 strings with a dot included

Tags: gnu-make

I am trying to implement a simple string comparison to get the type of a file (using its extension) like this:

```
extract_pkg: $(PKG)
    $(eval EXT := $(suffix $(PKG)))
    @echo $(EXT)
ifeq ($(EXT), .zip)
    @echo "is zip file"
else
    @echo "is not a zip file"
endif

extract_pkg : PKG = mypkg.zip
```

However, when I run it it goes into the else branch. My guess is, it has to do with the dot, but I dont find a solution. Thanks for your help !

Edit 1: the essential code would be actually somewhat like the following, and it works as expected:

```
test_cmp:
ifeq (.zip,.zip)
        @echo ".zip==.zip"
endif
ifeq (zip,zip)
        @echo "zip==zip"
endif
```

thus the problem is somewhere else !

Answer (score 10):

One thing to be careful about -- spaces in `if` constructs are significant.  So if you have something like:

```
ifeq ($(EXT), .zip)
```

it will only match if `$(EXT)` expands to exactly "`.zip`" -- including the space before the period.  So your first example will always print `is not a zip file`, since `$(EXT)` will never contain the space.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot use ifeq() etc. inside recipes.  ifeq() are preprocessor statements: they are interpreted immediately as the makefile is read in.  Recipes are not run until much later, after all makefiles are parsed and make decides that this target needs to be updated.  So trying to set a variable in a recipe using eval, etc. then test that variable using ifeq() cannot work.

You have to use shell constructs for this; something like:

```
extract_pkg: $(PKG)
        @EXT=$(suffix $<); \
         echo $$EXT; \
         if [ $$EXT = .zip ]; then \
            echo "is zip file"; \
        else \
            echo "is not a zip file"; \
        fi
```

Comment: this is a very old solution, but I wanted to thank you because this worked. I also wanted to ask, when I use this implementation, it echos out the entire if statement, is there a way to suppress that?

Comment: If you put the `@` at the beginning of the first line it won't print any of the recipe at all (above, it's `@EXT=...`)